# how to cancel sending the form

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I want that when capturing the submit event of the form it is validated if there is content inside the editor, all this works well but when I return false to avoid sending the form everything continues normally, any ideas?

*Form*

```
=form_tag new_answer_path(@item_type, @item_id, @thread_type, @thread_id), method: :post, class:"ui reply form", remote: :true do
  %input{type:"hidden", value:"#{ SecureRandom.uuid }", name:"secureRandom"}

  =hidden_field_tag :message
  #quillEditor.clean.small
  .ui.hidden.divider

  .uk-margin
    %button.uk-button.uk-button-text#send_reply{type:"submit", "data-animation":"ripple"} Enviar respuesta

  :javascript
    createQuill($("input[name=secureRandom]").last().val())
```

*JS Function*

```
function createQuill(secureRandom){
  let parent = $("input[value=" + secureRandom + "]").parent()[0]
  let editor = $(parent).find('#quillEditor')[0]
  let description = $(parent).find("input[name=message]")[0]

  let quill = new Quill(editor, {
    modules: {
      toolbar: [
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', { 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],        // toggled buttons
        [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }, { 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }, { 'align': [] }],
        ['link', 'image', 'video']                        // formula, image and video implement

      ]
    },
    placeholder: '✍️ Escribe algo...',
    theme: 'snow'
  });

  parent.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    description.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents())

    if($(description).val().replace(/\\/g,'').replace(/"/g, "") == "{ops:[{insert:n}]}"){
      return false
    }
  }.bind(this, description), false)
}
```

Comment: I think what your looking for is to add a `event.preventDefault()` before you `return false` in the `addEventListener`

Comment: @hajile78 I already tried that but it returns the following error: Uncaught TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: It is case sensitive so if you used `event.preventdefault()` instead of `event.preventDefault()` would explain why you got that error.

Comment: @hajile78 Yes, I knew that but it did not work.